# Ios how to pass google map userData to next view

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to pass google map's `userData` to next view when user tapped custom info window.

first I created model object like so.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

    struct Team {

        var key: String
        var teamName: String
        var league: String
        var lat: Double
        var lng: Double

        init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            self.key = snapshot.key
            self.teamName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["teamName"] as? String
            self.league = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["league"] as? String ?? ""
            self.lat = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
            self.lng = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["lng"] as? Double ?? 0
        }
    }
```

I fetched database and put `userData` like so

```
var teams = [Team?]()

    func fetchTeams(){

            let teamRef = Database.database().reference().child("teams")
            teamRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                var result = [Team]()

                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let child = Team(snapshot: child as! DataSnapshot)
                    result.append(child)
                    self.teams = result
                }

                for team in self.teams {
                    guard let lat = team?.lat else { return }
                    guard let lng = team?.lng else { return }
                    let marker: GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
                    marker.map = self.mapView
                    marker.userData = team
                }

            }, withCancel: nil)
        }
```

this `func` works perfectly so I guess `userData` has its property correctly.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
            let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Marker", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MarkerView

            infoWindow.teamLabel.text = (marker.userData as! Team).teamName

            return infoWindow
        }


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: cellId, sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == cellId {
            let next: NextViewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            next.team = marker.userData as? Team
        }
    }
```

I implemented like above to pass data to `NextViewController`.
it worked fine till `performSegue` but `next.team` is nil. Does anyone know why? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having that issue because you are creating an empty `GMSMarker` and of course this empty `GMSMarker` don't have any userData, you have to pass the selected `GMSMarker` as parameter in the `performSegue`, specifically in the `sender` parameter, and cast as `Team` and pass it to your `NextViewController`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: cellId, sender: marker.userData)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == cellId {
            let next: NextViewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            if let teamData = sender as? Team{
               next.team = teamData
               debugPrint("teamData is fine")
            }
            debugPrint("segue identifier is correct")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but still nil. I did `print(team)` in `viewDidLoad()` and I hit break point but never executed. Can you tell why it's not working.

Comment: @Daibaku the `prepare` method is being called?

Comment: I checked and actually it's not being called.

Comment: @Daibaku did you set the `self.mapView.delegate = self`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked segue and destination and those are correct.

Comment: can you check that your `didTapInfoWindowOf`of `GMSMapViewDelegate` is called? @Daibaku

Comment: Do you mean this func right? `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: cellCertificate, sender: self)
    }` it's called because it perform segue to NextViewController properly.

Comment: but your `prepare`method is not being called? can you put a breakPoint in the `if segue.identifier == cellId {`line and tell me if is called? @Daibaku

Comment: I found out that the problem is that senderMarker is nil. That's why it's not passing data.

Comment: @Daibaku but in `didTapInfoWindowOf` method is not nil?

Comment: Yeah that's not nil, it perform segue. Is this because I created custom infoWindow? So should I set sendor to infoWindow?

Comment: @Daibaku check my updated answer, and let me know if "segue identifier is correct" is printed

Comment: @Daibaku check again my answer and let me know if "teamData is fine" is printed

Comment: "segue identifier is correct" was printed again. Thank you so much for your generous help!

Comment: @Daibaku can you post your updated code in the question? did you update with my last answer? check if "teamData is fine" message is printed if is printed then your issue must be solved

Comment: I did! please take a look at it.

Comment: @Daibaku please also post the updated `didTapInfoWindowOf` method

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't realize the update if `didTapInfoWindowOf ` and it perfectly worked!! Thank you so much. You're life saver!!

Comment: Your Welcome @Daibaku glad to help you, best regards and happy code bro

Comment: Thank you bro I really appreciate it:)